# remove blank space at bottom that comes on min-width condition

Tags: html, css

below is my html css code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <title ng-bind="title +' | Game '">Platano</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
<style>
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border:1px red solid;
    height:100%;
    }
body{
    height:100%;
    border:1px black solid;
   background: linear-gradient(180deg,#007738,#B0D133);
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-width: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    z-index: -2;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

To observe this blank space on desktop..follow the steps

step 1: open this html file or code and open firebug...click on mobile icon in firebug as shown in figure below.
[image]

Step2: You will see the screen as shown below..now make sure that "Screen" checkbox is checked...as shown in image below

[image]

step 3: now reduce the screen size to less than 500 by selecting any device or dragging the screen (since i have set min-width:500px) and then refresh the page by (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>f5</kbd>) or (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>)..and now you can clearly see the blank space on the footer of the page..
[image]

Comment: Personally I would have the html and body CSS as just margin/padding 0. Then have a div with position absolute, top,left,right,bottom as 0 with the gradient bg. But you don't need height attribute etc. If you needed to force full height of body perhaps height 100vh might help

Comment: u mean height:100% ?

Comment: Like this I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/jd4h44os/ - does this work better?

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ:  bro...u didn;t mentioned min-width in the code...bcoz blank space is coming bcoz of min-width

Comment: In your fiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: In fiddle we cannot have environment of mobile...thats why i have posted above everthing in detail

Comment: why you are using absolute positioning..?

Comment: though there is a huge difference between relative and absolute...but in this case it does matter for the html tag position to be relative or absolute...
for the body tag..position is absolute...since the client wanted

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is, giving a definite positioning  to the body And also making it `left:0;` and also inserting a condition of `min-width:500px;`. 
so it causes html to expand according to screen, but your body section remains `left:0;` with fixed width `500px`. 
So, better you remove `left:0;` from body style. It will make your body a fluid container.

Comment: thanks @shudansh for trying..but still there is a blank space at the bottom

Comment: have you removed absolute positioning also?

Comment: no, do not remove absolute positioning.just remove left:0;

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you set page scale to `-0.8` as you can see in top right corner of your window. If you return it to 1 everything works fine.

Comment: even if it is set to 1...body height increases but the blank space still exists below the footer...if you scroll down you will get the blank space

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not clear what you are looking for.

Hope you need to show this linear gradient in all devices and its sizes.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg,#007738,#B0D133);
}
```

```html
<body>
   
</body>
```

Try this, else let me know what is your exact requirement.

Comment: My problem is...when the device width is less than 500px..then there is a unknown white space at the bottom of the page...it is not related to linear gradient

Comment: Can you run my code and check. If it is not you are looking for let me know what you are looking for

Comment: i want to remove blank space,,that is visible when device width is less than 500px...as shown in pics above

Comment: I checked in my browser and I didn't found any error in your code. Use a developer extension and check. I think your code is working fine..:). Don't override the extension.
Install Responsive Web Designer Tester or any other tester and check with that.

Answer (score 0):

This for any screen size - i have added in the `min-width` which forces you to scroll right on screens which are too small;

**Meta**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body, .game {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.game{
    border:1px black solid;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#007738,#B0D133);
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="game"></div>
```

**Full Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game.</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
        html,body, .game {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .game{
            border:1px black solid;
            background: linear-gradient(180deg,#007738,#B0D133);
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 16px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            min-width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="game"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot Example**
[image: IMG]